# Multiple matches in a MATCH statement in Cypher / Neo4j / Spring

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher

I have a Spring Application and in my Repository I have a query where I match Drugs and only ONE Patient but it is not defined how many drugs will be selected from the user.

Actual Cypher Query:

```
MATCH (p:Patient) where ID(p) = ({0})
MATCH (d:Drug) where ID(d) in [({1}),({2}),({3})]  
RETURN p, d
```

In this query, I am matching 3 Drugs but I would like this to be like a `for` statement depending on how many Drugs the user will select.

Something like that:

```
MATCH (p:Patient) where ID(p) = ({0})
MATCH (d:Drug) where ID(d) in [({1}),({2}),({3}),.....({10})] <-- size could be 1 or more
RETURN p, d
```

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to loop in Cypher somehow? If so, how do I solve my problem?

Comment: If your query works for a list of 3, that means it will also work for a list of 1 or more. It is not clear what you are asking, and why you think a for-loop is needed.

Comment: in my frontend the user is selecting Drugs in his Bag (could be 1 but could be also 10 or 100), then i want to select all this drugs by ID with this query. Thats the thing

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing the values as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/).

For example, if you use a `p_id` parameter to pass the ID of the `Patient`, and a `d_ids` parameter to pass a *collection* of `Drug` IDs:

```
MATCH (p:Patient) WHERE ID(p) = $p_id
MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE ID(d) IN $d_ids
RETURN p, d
```